# Reuse iframe in another tab (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I have this iframe in a page: `document.querySelector("iframe")`

It loads a PDF from a server. **to avoid calling another request when the user clicks on a button i want to reuse the iframe with the pdf document** from this iframe: ex: `<iframe src="myAPI/loadPdf.pdf"><iframe>`

When a user clicks a button:

```
var pdfWindow = window.open("");
console.log(document.querySelector("iframe"));
pdfWindow.document.write(document.querySelector("iframe"));
//to avoid making 2 request, use the one that is already loaded
```

This writes `[object HTMLIFrameElement]` on the blank page instead of the document

Comment: Yes. I already loaded on the first page. When the user clicks a button I want open the document from the iframe but in another page but without loading again from the server

Comment: @brooksrelyt Hey there. I will assume you made a mistake, but changing the title like you did in your [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21889499) borders on vandalism. Please take extra case in making sure you keep the original intent when editing posts.

Comment: the browser's cache could take control of this. us `header("Cache-Control: max-age=2592000"); ` if you're using php

Answer (score 0):

`document.write()` writes a string to the document. You want to append the `iframe` node to `document.body`:

```
pdfWindow.document.body.appendChild(document.querySelector('iframe'))
```

**But note that** when you append the iframe you can see a request for the pdf file in the network panel, however if the browser could cache the file and the cached version is available then the cached version is used and it's not downloaded again. With that said it's actually no use to reuse the `iframe` since the same thing happens if you just open the window with the url to the pdf file, the cached version will be used if it's available.